# POST request to Google Reader (mark as readed)

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-reader

I'm trying to mark an item as read on Google Reader using cURL and PHP. I'm requesting Google Reader permission for my application using OAuth 2.0. When I tried to mark an item as read, got the "400 Bad Request" HTTP error, my request looks like:

URL: https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag

URL Params:

```
[client] => scroll
```

POST Params:

```
[i] => tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/b25079e56615b397
[s] => feed/http://christophertimberlake.com/rss
[async] => true
[T] => <Access token got on OAuth2 sign-in>
[a] => user/<user-id>/state/com.google/read
```

Request headers:

```
[Host] => www.google.com
[Accept] => */*
[Authorization] => Bearer <OAuth2 access token>
[Referer] => http://www.google.com/reader/view/
[User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
[Content-Length] => 247
[Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Also, I'm noticed a strange response header from Google: `X-reader-google-bad-token: true`. Is this header related to the token sent by POST, do I have to use the OAuth2 token as POST parameter or I need another token?

Please note that I was successful to perform read-only request like get subscriptions, items list or read count information.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, using OAuth2 I need also an action token to perform non read-only operations.

See more

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fougrapi/U_8eT4yyLsY